# In an AngularJs directive, how do I call its controller's function contained within an directive element's attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I am trying to call a function in a controller, which is part of a custom angular directive, following is the code,

**Method 1:** (Doesn't work: Controller's function doesn't write to the console)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <my-directive callback-fn="ctrlFn(arg1)"></my-directive>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { someCtrlFn: '&callbackFn' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.someCtrlFn({arg1: 22});
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.ctrlFn = function(test) {
                console.log(test);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I remove the directive's controller from it and and create a new controller it works,

**Method 2:** (Works: Controller's function does write to the console)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <my-directive callback-fn="ctrlFn(arg1)"></my-directive>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { someCtrlFn: '&callbackFn' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.someCtrlFn({arg1: 22});
        }
    }
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ctrlFn = function(test) {
        console.log(test);
    }
});
```

I would like know how to get the behavior of **Method 2** in **Method 1** i.e., to be able to call the directive's controller's function from directive's attribute.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved it using $rootScope instead of $scope within the directive's controller

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <my-directive callback-fn="ctrlFn(arg1)"></my-directive>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { someCtrlFn: '&callbackFn' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.someCtrlFn({arg1: 22});
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $rootScope.ctrlFn = function(test) {
                console.log(test);
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Method 1**, you are creating an isolated scope and defining a scope value `someCtrlFn` that takes in a function from the parent scope that is using your directive. The function to use is specified by the attribute `callbackFn`.

The way directives work with these scope items is that they are expected to be assigned from things that are on the parent scope that is active when the directive is used. So, if you have a controller `Ctrl` as in your **Method 2**, then use the directive within that scope, your directive is trying to match the what you defined in the attribute to what is available on `Ctrl`'s scope.

So, in your first example, it's looking for a function called `ctrlFn` on the parent scope, but there isn't one. It will not try to look for it on the directive's controller. This is why **Method 2** works, because there is a parent scope where `ctrlFn` is defined, and the directive is able to properly invoke that expression.

The purpose of these scope attributes is to allow directives to bind to values or functions on a parent scope to facilitate communication. For example, to give the directive data that it will display or modify, or allow the parent to define a function the directive can invoke for a callback during an event or what have you. The parent scope cannot move into the directive's scope and force the directive's scope to use its own defined items (unless you set it up so your directive uses a default value or function if the attribute is omitted or whatever).

They are not used so a directive can define things on its scope that it uses internally. If these things are internal to the directive, you can simply add them to the scope during `link` or whatever is suitable.

Did you mean something like this?

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // defines ctrlFn that can be used later by this directive's template or controller
            scope.ctrlFn = function(test) {
                console.log(test);
            }

            // immediately invokes ctrlFn to log a message, just here to illustrate
            scope.ctrlFn('Hello World!');
        }
    }
});
```